# Android POST JSON to PHP

Tags: android

**Hi, i want to POST JSON to a PHP-Script.**
Here is the code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
for(int k = 0; k<len;k++){
   obj.put("nachrichten_ids", params[k]);
}               
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("xxxxxx");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nachrichten_ids",obj.toString()));

httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

The PHP Script contains actually only print_r($_POST),- **and its empty every time.**

**Where is the problem ?**

**Log.i("TEST",obj.toString()) outputs:**
{"nachrichten_ids":"[2144,2138]"}

Where each number are IDS for messages that should be deleted.

Comment: One problem may be that you're not using the JSON serialization, so your body is probably never in JSON format. By the way, your JSON sequence is enclosed in "" -- that can't work either.

Comment: Hi,ok. What does that mean? How to "Json serialize" ? And whats wrong with my Json sequence,- how to do this correctly ?

Comment: C'mon don't be so lazy. Look at Android's JSONObject reference or Manmeet's code below. Maybe you get the point when you ask yourself a question: _What is the JSONObject in my code even good for if I have to code like I did in the snippet provided with my question?_

Comment: ...by the way, why do you expect something to show up in $_POST if you truly intend to send JSON (which, on the other hand, you don't do)?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
/**
     * Functionality of HTTP POST and return response
     * @param url to hit
     * @param json object to post
     * 
     * @return string response
    */
        public String httpPostWithJson(String url, JSONObject json)
        {
            String result = "";
            try
            {
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 60000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(myParams, true);

                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);


               StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8); 
               se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
               httppost.setEntity(se); 

              // Execute HTTP Post Request
               HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //        Log.e("","response code = "+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() );
              if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
              {
                  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                  result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
              }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
    //          Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Please ask your server guys to check on their end and also ask to check your json packet, is there is any need to change by your end...

Answer (score -1):

**So, now its working. I have used the lib "Gson":**

```
    final ArrayList<String> delMessagesId = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for(int i=0;i<nachrichtenListe.size();i++){
      Nachricht nachricht = nachrichtenListe.get(i);
      if(nachricht.isSelected() == true){
        delMessagesId.add(nachricht.nachricht_id); 
       }
    }

    String ddate = new Gson().toJson(params);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("xxx");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nachrichten_ids", ddate));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    // Get the return string (JSON data)
    String temp = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    Log.i("TEST",temp);
```

Comment: Look, on the bottom line, the code snippet doesn't utilize JSON at all, so I suggest you eliminate Gson as well because it's just a waste of CPU time. Also, the title of your question is completely wrong because you don't send JSON to your server; instead, you send a plain old form body. However, as I noted in another comment, you don't seem to expect JSON on the server side, either (given your _print_r($_POST)_ remark in the original post). So: Is using JSON a requirement? If so, your answer here is worthless. If not, then why did you ask for a JSON solution?